# If $y=9\sec^2x+16\csc^2x$,find the minimum value of $y$

Tags: trigonometry

If $y=9\sec^2x+16\csc^2x$,find the minimum value of $y,\hspace{1cm}\forall x\in R$

---

$y=9\sec^2x+16\csc^2x$
$\frac{dy}{dx}=18\sec^2x\tan x-32\csc^2 x\cot x$
Put $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$
$18\sec^2x\tan x-32\csc^2 x\cot x=0$
It gives $\tan^2x=\frac{4}{3}$
So $\sec^2x=\frac{5}{3}$ and $\csc^2 x=\frac{5}{4}$
Which gives $y=9\sec^2x+16\csc^2x=35$ but the answer given is $49$.I dont know where i am wrong.I tried another method.
$y=9\sec^2x+16\csc^2x=(3\sec x+4\csc x)^2-24\sec x\csc x$ but i am stuck here.

Comment: May be easier to first put $y=9\sec^2x+16\csc^2x = \frac{9}{\cos^2 x} + \frac{16}{\sin^2 x}$ which can be written as $y = \frac{9 \sin^2 x + 16 \cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x \cos^2 x}$. Now use $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ so that $y= \frac{9 + 7 \cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x \cos^2 x}$. The next step is to use the identities $\cos 2x = 2 \cos^2 x -1$ and $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$. This gives $y = 2 \frac{18 + 7 \cos 2x}{\sin^2 2x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is going from $\tan^2x=\frac43$ to $\sec^2x=\frac53$, $\csc^2x=\frac54$. Actually this means $\tan x=\frac2{\sqrt3}$, so $\sec x=\frac{\sqrt7}{\sqrt3}$ and $\csc x=\frac{\sqrt7}{2}$, giving $\sec^2x=\frac73$ and $\csc^2x=\frac74$.

Comment: Or quicker, $\sec^2x=1+\tan^2x,\,\csc^2x=1+1/\tan^2x$.

Answer (score 3):

$$9\sec^2x+16\csc^2x=9(1+\tan^2x)+16(1+\cot^2x)$$
$$=9+16+(3\tan x-4\cot x)^2+2\cdot3\tan x\cdot4\cot x\ge25+24$$

The equality occurs if $3\tan x-4\cot x=0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint do it with $tan$ so you get $y=\frac{25\tan^2(x)+tan^4(x)+16}{tan^2(x)}$ now differentiate or better way is AM-GM ie $$9sec^2(x)+16\csc^2(x)\geq 24\sqrt{sec^2(x)csc^2(x)}$$ now $sec^2(x)csc^2(x)=(1+t^2)(1+1/t^2)=(tan(x)+cot(x))^2$